# Что такое ECMAScript Harmony?

Tags: javascript

1. Что такое ECMAScript Harmony?
2. Какими браузерами он поддерживается?
3. Что про него нужно знать ещё?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну [гуглиться](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ecmascript-harmony) же ответ :|

1. Это следущая версия ECMAScript, он же ES6 или  ES.next
2. Частично [FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla), но есть трансляторы из ES6 в ES5
3. Что уже пора начинать его использовать (см. пункт 2)

Comment: @RubaXa, Спасибо! Про гуглится, я именно из гугла и пришел и даже часть статьи прочел по первой ссылке, но полной картины я не могу самостоятельно сложить, так как в js я новичок и не знаю все предыстории.  
Можно ещё уточнить - когда он будет полность реализован, то будет ли во всех браузерах или только в FF?  
И появилась ещё множество вопросов, но пока мне их рано задавать и я скрипя зубами отложу их. Но один все же задам, до встречи в нем. :)

Comment: Да не важно когда, всегда будет лаг в сколько-то версий версий браузеров, главное что уже сейчас есть инструменты, которые позволяют использовать все возможности и это будет прекрасно работать даже в каком-нибудь IE8.

P.S. Вот ещё ссылочка http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: А Вам никогда не приходилось ES6 на nodejs запускать? Если нововведения, такие как class symbol работают, то я бы тему создал и спросил, как запустить.

Comment: Не пробовал, мне NodeJS не особо интересен, и надеюсь, вы не задумали  эмулировать private через Symbol.

Comment: Да... Я делаю маленький плагин для nodejs и был бы не против использовать ES6 и его новшества. А что такого?